# Kong API gateway Oauth2 grant_type=password invalid_client error no matter what I change

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I have been setting up Kong locally and testing different kinds of setups.  Currently I have kong running inside docker-compose with access to the gateway making requests.  Passing in these env variables

```sh
environment:
  - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
  - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
  - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
  - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
  - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
  - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001
  - KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong
  - KONG_PG_HOST=postgres.me.io
  - KONG_PG_USER=username
  - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=password
  - KONG_TRUSTED_IPS=0.0.0.0/0
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=kong.me.io
  - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
```

I am trying to setup the oauth2 plugin with the the `grant_type=password`.  I am constantly getting `invalid_client` error with nothing in the logs to really tell me whats going on.  I have tried following https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/2446 without any luck even removing the `client_id` doesnt work.  There doesn't seem to be any other information out there that indicates whats going on.  I have added `trusted_ips` to the envs so that I dont run it over ssl, which if you dont gives an error of `Must use https`.  What am I doing wrong to make this work?  This seemed to be the easiest implementation but it doesn't like anything.

## Add a service for backend apis routes

`http POST http://kong.me.io:8001/services name=me.io.apis host=api.me.io port:=5000`

```sh
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 300
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 22:33:54 GMT
Server: kong/1.4.0
X-Kong-Admin-Latency: 232

{
    "client_certificate": null,
    "connect_timeout": 60000,
    "created_at": 1574462034,
    "host": "api.me.io",
    "id": "6f12367c-d92b-4334-a654-8f2d706b70e6",
    "name": "me.io.apis",
    "path": null,
    "port": 5000,
    "protocol": "http",
    "read_timeout": 60000,
    "retries": 5,
    "tags": null,
    "updated_at": 1574462034,
    "write_timeout": 60000
}
```

## Create a route for backend apis paths

`http POST http://kong.me.io:8001/services/6f12367c-d92b-4334-a654-8f2d706b70e6/routes hosts:='["api.me.io"]' paths:='["/apis"]'`

```sh
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 417
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 22:34:29 GMT
Server: kong/1.4.0
X-Kong-Admin-Latency: 22

{
    "created_at": 1574462069,
    "destinations": null,
    "headers": null,
    "hosts": [
        "api.me.io"
    ],
    "https_redirect_status_code": 426,
    "id": "92ff918e-2a05-4768-866e-3a3061d563e4",
    "methods": null,
    "name": null,
    "paths": [
        "/apis"
    ],
    "preserve_host": false,
    "protocols": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "regex_priority": 0,
    "service": {
        "id": "6f12367c-d92b-4334-a654-8f2d706b70e6"
    },
    "snis": null,
    "sources": null,
    "strip_path": true,
    "tags": null,
    "updated_at": 1574462069
}
```

## Create Oauth  plugin on backend routes

`http POST http://kong.me.io:8001/services/6f12367c-d92b-4334-a654-8f2d706b70e6/plugins name=oauth2 config:='{"enable_password_grant": true, "accept_http_if_already_terminated": true}'`

```sh
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 682
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 22:35:19 GMT
Server: kong/1.4.0
X-Kong-Admin-Latency: 139

{
    "config": {
        "accept_http_if_already_terminated": true,
        "anonymous": null,
        "auth_header_name": "authorization",
        "enable_authorization_code": false,
        "enable_client_credentials": false,
        "enable_implicit_grant": false,
        "enable_password_grant": true,
        "global_credentials": false,
        "hide_credentials": false,
        "mandatory_scope": false,
        "provision_key": "uijq0y4dBFZITqirZ9QJr18DeHjaMpXS",
        "refresh_token_ttl": 1209600,
        "scopes": null,
        "token_expiration": 7200
    },
    "consumer": null,
    "created_at": 1574462119,
    "enabled": true,
    "id": "c3d21c32-9062-49bd-a2b0-66b4fa6ac320",
    "name": "oauth2",
    "protocols": [
        "grpc",
        "grpcs",
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "route": null,
    "run_on": "first",
    "service": {
        "id": "6f12367c-d92b-4334-a654-8f2d706b70e6"
    },
    "tags": null
}
```

## Create a consumer to test with

`http POST http://kong.me.io:8001/consumers username=me@me.com custom_id=5b6215eed6814902e4d53d24`

```sh
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 162
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 22:37:29 GMT
Server: kong/1.4.0
X-Kong-Admin-Latency: 20

{
    "created_at": 1574462249,
    "custom_id": "5b6215eed6814902e4d53d24",
    "id": "f1b5fb00-df6e-4089-b4b8-639ceb4e6a80",
    "tags": null,
    "username": "me@me.com"
}
```

## Add a client id to the test consumer

`http POST http://kong.me.io:8001/consumers/f1b5fb00-df6e-4089-b4b8-639ceb4e6a80/oauth2 name='me@me.com'`

```sh
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 295
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 22:41:21 GMT
Server: kong/1.4.0
X-Kong-Admin-Latency: 29

{
    "client_id": "03N4ehIbe44hYhnjGwO8hfW8jTHnxLSL",
    "client_secret": "nfW39yTNiDEVShtVIHovjC1aXm1VlxPd",
    "consumer": {
        "id": "f1b5fb00-df6e-4089-b4b8-639ceb4e6a80"
    },
    "created_at": 1574462481,
    "id": "d533d1ad-3d2b-47ef-af87-33f7b14dbb88",
    "name": "me@me.com",
    "redirect_uris": null,
    "tags": null
}
```

## Test that you can get keys back from kong

`http POST http://api.me.io:8080/apis/oauth2/token "x-forwarded-proto: https" authenticated_userid="5b6215eed6814902e4d53d24" client_id="03N4ehIbe44hYhnjGwO8hfW8jTHnxLSL" client_secret="nfW39yTNiDEVShtVIHovjC1aXm1VlxPd" grant_type=password provision_key="uijq0y4dBFZITqirZ9QJr18DeHjaMpXS" username="me@me.com" password="password" -vv`

```sh
POST /apis/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 301
Content-Type: application/json
Host: api.me.io:8080
User-Agent: HTTPie/1.0.2
x-forwarded-proto: https

{
    "authenticated_userid": "5b6215eed6814902e4d53d24",
    "client_id": "03N4ehIbe44hYhnjGwO8hfW8jTHnxLSL",
    "client_secret": "nfW39yTNiDEVShtVIHovjC1aXm1VlxPd",
    "grant_type": "password",
    "password": "password",
    "provision_key": "uijq0y4dBFZITqirZ9QJr18DeHjaMpXS",
    "username": "me@me.com"
}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 78
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 22:45:14 GMT
Server: kong/1.4.0
X-Kong-Response-Latency: 25
cache-control: no-store
pragma: no-cache

{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Invalid client authentication"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do it over https(using port 8443 instead). You need to do something like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  --url "https://api.me.io:8443/apis/oauth2/token " \
  --header "Host: api.me.io" \
  --data "grant_type=password" \
  --data "client_id=03N4ehIbe44hYhnjGwO8hfW8jTHnxLSL" \
  --data "client_secret=nfW39yTNiDEVShtVIHovjC1aXm1VlxPd" \
  --data "provision_key=uijq0y4dBFZITqirZ9QJr18DeHjaMpXS"\
  --data "redirect_uri=http://localhost/cb/" \
  --data "authenticated_userid=me@me.com"  \
  --insecure
```

you should as well specify a redirect uri(which wont be called anyway).Im not sure why this is so but adding that gave me less headache. You can follow this [link](https://github.com/Kong/kong-oauth2-hello-world) for more details on how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

you need add a redirect url in the Consumer credential oauth, or what this tutorial https://medium.com/@far3ns/kong-oauth-2-0-plugin-38faf938a468#f9d5 calls an application, if you do so it will not fall in this if

```lua
local allowed_redirect_uris, client = get_redirect_uris(client_id)
    if not (grant_type == GRANT_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS) then
      if allowed_redirect_uris then
        local redirect_uri = parameters[REDIRECT_URI] and
          parameters[REDIRECT_URI] or
          allowed_redirect_uris[1]

        if not table_contains(allowed_redirect_uris, redirect_uri) then
          response_params = {
            [ERROR] = "invalid_request",
            error_description = "Invalid " .. REDIRECT_URI .. " that does " ..
              "not match with any redirect_uri created "  ..
              "with the application"
          }
        end
```